# Deleting all Records after a specific string is found in one record in one field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am uploading a table from excel, and some junk records are coming along with it. Specifically, in the first field after all the data I need comes through, I get a record that contains the phrase "(random number) of (random number) records came through." I would like to delete all the records after the this phrase. What I am trying to do right now is find the position of this record, using a method like DoCmd.Seek or Findfirst, but am not sure if this is the correct way. Once I found this position, I would do something like `DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete from table where field in (select bottom (total records - position of phrase "records came through") field from tblCopyUtlwos);", False`But am unsure how to find the position of that phrase in the field. Any tips for finding the position, or better ways for deleting the records below the phrase in the field would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered an import with an auto number generated by MS Access, you would then have the option of deleting where Id > anumber

Comment: As for a phrase, look at instr

Comment: Typically in a database you don't ever rely on unsorted records having any kind of "order" to them: there is no real guarantee (without using an "order by" clause) of the order in which records will be selected, so there's no concept of "before" or "after". You need something like @Fionnuala suggests - a specific field you can use to indicate order of insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel doesn't have tables, it has spreadsheets.  Maybe that's nitpicking, but it's a pet peeve of mine when people refer to Excel as a "database".

As for the problem at hand, you can import the data using a Primary Key.  Stick it into a field called PKey.  This will allow you to find where the record is that you want to delete.

Then, do something like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim MySQL as String

Set db = CurrentDB
'Find the PKey of the record you want to search for
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("SELECT PKey FROM tblCopyUtlwos WHERE MyField LIKE '*Records Came Through*'")

'Now you have the Primary Key # where that phrase appears
'Delete all records where the Primary Key is greater than or equal to that Primary Key #
MySQL = "DELETE FROM tblCopyUtlwos WHERE PKey >= " & rec(0) & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL MySQL
```

This is all "air code" and isn't tested, and you'll have to make obvious edits where your table names/field names differ, but it should set you on the right track.

Comment: I get an error when I try to "Dim db as Database" it says user-defined type not defined @Johnny Bones

Comment: Check your references and make sure none say "Missing".  That should be an automatic, I'm not even sure which reference controls it because it's always there for me.  You're doing this in Access, right?